# Conditional Compiling for iOS and Simulator in XCode 4.x

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can anybody help me around for compiling the app differently for iOS and Simulator as I've two static library for iOS and Simulator because warning is coming if its compiling for either platform. Lipo command can resolve the warning issue but I want that for Simulator and iOS separate compilation to be happen.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set up separate targets for device and simulator.  In the target for the simulator, in build settings, make "Supported Platforms" be only "iphonesimulator."  In the other targets that build for device, make the "Supported Platforms" be only "iphoneos."  Remove any supported platforms not intended for your target.  In this case, your SIM target may also be able to select a device, but it's easy to manually support that.  Then you go to the specific library and turn it off for your sim build.

Comment: Added thought:  Using the above, in my device targets, I can only select a device,  in the sim targets, I can select a host of simulators (whatever I've in stalled).  I can also select the device in sim mode, but it's easy to notice this (as you have to select SIM target), and might even be a feature if you need a build without that library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source you can add something like the following around the code that gives warnings:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR 
 // do the simulator thing
#else
 // do the device thing
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the warnings are not in code. Its the static library i.e. if I compile for Simulator then its showing warning for static library of device and vice-versa. I think something has to be done with Conditional compiling in Build Settings.